# How to create role programatically in liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

I would like to create a role from hook plugin. I am using liferay 6.1.1. I tried RoleLocalServiceUtil API, but could not find suitable way. Any Help?

Thanks.

Comment: just to make sure : you want to create a NEW ROLE programatically? or ADD a role to a USER ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check RoleServiceUtil addRole method ?

Comment: Yes, in Liferay 6.1, the following should create the regular role "Foobar": `RoleServiceUtil.addRole("Foobar", null, null, 0);`